# How to call a public static async void in Main console app?

Tags: c#, tfs

I have the below class `GetProjectClass`, with `public static async void GetProjects()`

I want to call this method/class so it does "something" pretty new to Asynchronous programming – goal is to connect to TFS, pragmatically

I have the below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
public class GetProjectClass
{
public static async void GetProjects()
{
try
{
var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(

new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(                    "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects").Result)

{response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
}
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
}
}
}
```

The below is my program.cs file, wanting to call the above, was wondering if this was possible

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            GetProjectClass t = new GetProjectClass();
            t.GetProjects().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since `GetProjects` is `async void` you cannot wait on it.  I'd suggest changing it to return `Task` and actually using `await` inside where appropriate.

Comment: To add to what juharr is saying, you should generally never have `async void` methods. `async void` would only be used for Events, so return a `Task` instead

Comment: If you're in an async method, always use await on other async methods if you need the result of that method. Don't use the .Result() this is a blocking call and can also cause dead lock issues sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with [C# 7.1 you can use async main methods](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/05/30/c-7-series-part-2-async-main/):

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        GetProjectClass t = new GetProjectClass();
        await t.GetProjects();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Pre C# 7.1 this was not possible.
**NOTE:** Yo need to change `GetProjects` to return a Task to get this working.